# What prevents a pool miner from stealing the block if they find the solution?

Tags: mining-pools, development

I'm learning about BC mining from a developmental level and I'm reading about how a pool delegates shares based on work, but it doesn't explain why the miner who finally finds the correct hash can't steal it from the pool - "turn it in" so to speak (I haven't learned how turning it in works yet, I should mention)

What prevents a pool miner from stealing the block if they find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

> [7] You might wonder why a miner doesn't cheat. If they successfully mine a block, why not submit it themselves so they can claim the full mining reward, rather than splitting it? The main reason is the coinbase transaction has the pool's address, not the miner's address. If the miner submits the block bypassing the pool, the reward still goes to the pool. And if the miner changes the address, the hash is no longer valid. - righto.com